# Request information from OpenID provider with Ruby

Tags: ruby, openid, sinatra

Im currently using ruby-openid gem to work with OpenID providers within my Sinatra application, but i cannot get information fields.

This is an example request:

```
openid_url = 'blahblah'
resp = openid.begin(openid_url)
resp.add_extension_arg('sreg','required','email')
resp.add_extension_arg('sreg','optional','fullname,nickname,dob,gender')
redirect_url = response.redirect_url('http://localhost:4567', 'http://localhost:4567/complete')
redirect redirect_url
```

Parse result fields:

```
info = response.extension_response('sreg',true)
```

I can login with most providers like Google, Yahoo, myOpenId, ... 
But the problem: i cant get the email information from all of them. Also, i cant get any information from Google`s openid.

So, how to solve this? Am i doing something wrong ?

Comment: May this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787894/ruby-openid-requiring-email-address-from-openid-provider - can point you in the right direction?